# Python local scope in if block issue

Tags: python, dictionary, scope

```
import re
def get_version_from_string(text):
    pattern = re.compile("^(\d+\.)*[0-9]{1,5}")
    match = pattern.match(text)
    return str(match.group(0))

findings = [
    {
        "attributes": [            
            {
                "key": "BENCHMARK_RULE_ID",
                "value": "0.0.0 Ensure permissions"
            }
            {
                "key": "INSTANCE_ID",
                "value": "i-6e0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "attributes": [           
            {
                "key": "BENCHMARK_RULE_ID",
                "value": "0.0.1 Ensure That files"
            }
            {
                "key": "INSTANCE_ID",
                "value": "i-6e0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "attributes": [               
            {
                "key": "BENCHMARK_RULE_ID",
                "value": "0.0.2 Ensure successful file"
            }
            {
                "key": "INSTANCE_ID",
                "value": "i-6e0"
            }
        ]
    }
]

non_compliant_instances = {}
cis_id = ""
instance = "dummy_value"
for finding in findings:
    for attribute in finding.get("attributes"):
        if attribute.get("key") == "INSTANCE_ID":
            instance = attribute.get("value")
        if instance not in non_compliant_instances:
            non_compliant_instances[instance] = {"CIS_Violations": [], "CVE_ID": []}
        if attribute.get("key") == "BENCHMARK_RULE_ID":
            cis_id = get_version_from_string(attribute.get("value"))
            non_compliant_instances[instance]["CIS_Violations"].append(cis_id)

# Actual Output:
print(non_compliant_instances)

# Work Around Starts
# Deleting first extra element
extra_cis_id = non_compliant_instances['aws'].get("CIS_Violations")

try:
    del non_compliant_instances['dummy_value']
except:
    print('No dummy_value found')

for ncinstance in non_compliant_instances.keys():
    set1 = set(non_compliant_instances.get(ncinstance).get('CIS_Violations'))
    set1.add(extra_cis_id[0])
    non_compliant_instances[ncinstance]["CIS_Violations"] = sorted(set1) 
# Work Around Ends

# Required Output:
print(non_compliant_instances)
```

Actual output is:

{{'dummy_value': {'CIS_Violations': ['0.0.0'], 'CVE_ID': []}, 'i-6e0': {'CIS_Violations': ['0.0.1', '0.0.2'], 'CVE_ID': []}}

Required output:

{'i-6e0': {'CIS_Violations': ['0.0.0', '0.0.1', '0.0.2'], 'CVE_ID': []}}

It happens because the value set to the **instance** variable by

```
if attribute.get("key") == "INSTANCE_ID":
            instance = attribute.get("value")
```

is local to that if block

only if it was possible to declare the variable instance as static without the OOPS....

Comment: "is local to that if block" code blocks do not create a scope in Python. Python scopes are module, class, and function. I honestly have no idea what you are asking. Can you provide a [mcve] of the behavior you are seeing that you weren't expecting? Most of this code is probably unnecessary to demonstrate whatever behavior is confusing you.

Comment: The problem is quite the opposite: `instance` is *not* local to the `if` statement, but if the `if` statement isn't executed, `instance` is never defined, period.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is the minimum code for anyone to reproduce the problem. I am getting the output I want due to the work around code. I just want a logic that would give the same required output without the ugly work around...

Comment: @chepner  yes you are right, but as you can see from the **findings** list variable, the first if condition is always true, hence **instance** variable gets defined. Is there any way to get the value it attained inside that if block to be accessible outside the if block...

Comment: It *is* available outside the `if` block. But in your loop, you are going to handle the `BENCHMARK_RULE_ID` before you ever have a chance to set the value of `instance`. This is not a scope issue.